# Check if wait_for_message comes from a certain user and types a certain message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to do a command that asks a user that is mentioned in the command like that `sir pls testinput @user` if he wants to play. If he answers with `sir pls testinput accept` then he should do something.

My approach to this was(which sadly doesn't work because it has no attribue `content` and probably also not `author`.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def testinput(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    await bot.say('Do you want to play {}? If yes type **sir pls testinput accept**.'.format(user.mention))
    response = bot.wait_for_message(author=user, content="sir pls testinput accept", timeout=30)
    if response.content == "sir pls testinput accept" and response.author == user:
        await bot.say('User {} decided to play with you {}'.format(user, ctx.message.author))
    else:
        await bot.say('Debug: Skipped the if statement')
```

Comment: `wait_for_message` is a coroutine. You just need to add `await` before it so it can yield the message back to you. So `response = await bot.wait_for_message`

Comment: Omg, I tried to debug this command for a hour and I forgot only `await` before the command. I feel so dumb right now xD. Thank you so much @Tristo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Tristo said in the comments, I forgot to add `await` before the command as it's a coroutine.

The working command looks like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def testinput(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    await bot.say('Do you want to play {}? If yes type **sir pls testinput accept**.'.format(user.mention))
    response = await bot.wait_for_message(author=user, content="sir pls testinput accept", timeout=30)
    if response.content == "sir pls testinput accept" and response.author == user:
        await bot.say('User {} decided to play with you {}'.format(user, ctx.message.author))
    else:
        await bot.say('Debug: Skipped the if statement')
```